# event.bind() is not a function in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, bind

So, i'm trying to update my command handler (using code lyons latest one), but i keep getting the error
client.on(event_name, event.bind(null, Discord, client));
TypeError: event.bind is not a function"

Here is my code (in event_handler.js):

```js
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (client, Discord) => {
    const load_dir = (dirs) =>{
        const event_files = fs.readdirSync(`./events/${dirs}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

        for(const file of event_files){
            const event = require(`../events/${dirs}/${file}`);
            const event_name = file.split('.')[0];
            client.on(event_name, event.bind(null, Discord, client));
        }
    }

    ['client', 'guild'].forEach(e => load_dir(e));
}
```

Comment: But the event variable is a require function, isn't it?

Comment: bind method is **only** made for js functions